# robots.txt file disallow root directory wordpress

Tags: search-engine

now in wordpress there is a file named wp-config.php and it contains all the passwords to database. If i allow google bot to index the whole web folder without disallowing root folder will the wp-config.php file be indexed ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it won't. The php will be executed when that file is viewed, and at the top, it has code which tells the server to spit out an empty page. Anyone who browses to that URL will see just a blank page. Verify this yourself...

Answer (score 0):

No it won't I guess. allow google bot to index and check whether you can access the wp-config.php as third party user.